# Python - Sum of column values between 2 dates

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, time-series

I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe:

Let X be a variable number of days.

|  | Date | Units Sold | Total Units sold in the last X days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 19:00:00 | 5 |  |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 15:00:00 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 2019-01-05 11:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2019-01-12 12:00:00 | 3 |  |
| 4 | 2019-01-15 15:00:00 | 2 |  |
| 5 | 2019-02-04 18:00:00 | 7 |  |

For each row, I need to sum up units sold + all the units sold in the last 10 days (letting x = 10 days)

Desired Result:

|  | Date | Units Sold | Total Units sold in the last X days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 19:00:00 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 15:00:00 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 2019-01-05 11:00:00 | 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 2019-01-12 12:00:00 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2019-01-15 15:00:00 | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 2019-02-04 18:00:00 | 7 | 7 |

I have used the `.rolling(window=)` method before using periods and I think the following can help

`df = df.rolling("10D").sum()`  but I can't get the syntax right!!

Please please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Total Units sold in the last 10 days"] = df.rolling(on="Date", window="10D", closed="both").sum()["Units Sold"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Date  Units Sold  Total Units sold in the last 10 days
0 2019-01-01           5                                   5.0
1 2019-01-01           4                                   9.0
2 2019-01-05           1                                  10.0
3 2019-01-12           3                                   4.0
4 2019-01-15           2                                   6.0
5 2019-02-04           7                                   7.0
```

Comment: Does it matter that my data is in 2019-01-01 19:00:00 format? My error is "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (500, 2), indices imply (500, 1)". My data is 500 rows

Comment: @hewokiti Did you put `["Units Sold"]` at the end of expression? You are trying to pass two columns of data to one column.

Comment: I did... earlier in the code I sorted by date and reset the index. Would that cause this issue?

Comment: I took out df.reset() index operation I did and it fixed the problem. Sorry I didn't mention it in the post, I didn't realize that it mattered. THANK YOU!!